# how to change date format in xlwt and how to set up a foreign key on django?

Tags: django

models.py

```
class Admission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    id_type = models.ForeignKey(
    'Type',
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='type',
    )

class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,db_index=True)
```

views.py

```
def export_users_xls(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="users.xls"'

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Admission')

    row_num = 0

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True

    columns = ['date', 'type', 'name']

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()

    rows = Admission.objects.all().values_list(
        'date', 'id_type', 'name'
    )
    print(rows)
    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

urls.py

```
path(r'^export/xls/$', export_users_xls, name='export_users_xls'),
```

I want to export data to an excel file.
in the exсel file, numbers are displayed instead of the date, and the value of the foreign key is as the model id.
how can this be fixed?

Comment: Please make sure your code is indented properly. I've edited it on this question.

Comment: there was no indentation in the model, I fixed

Answer (score 0):

For the foreign key value use
id_type__name or whatever you want to show from that model

Your code should look like

```
font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
date_style = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='YYYY/MM/DD')


rows = Admission.objects.all().values_list('date', 'id_type__name', 'name')

for row in rows:
    row_num += 1
    for col_num in range(len(row)):
        if isinstance(row[col_num], datetime.date):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], date_style)
        else:
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
```